# B2C sign in delays

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Working on a situation where the B2C user registration does not use the B2C Sign-up flow. Here the users sign up/register on the organization’s website, an Azure Function running on the organization’s Azure tenant picks up on the registration and then sends the user a notification email. The user clicks on a “Confirm your account” link on the email, this action enables the account and redirects the user to the organization’s B2C app to sign in. it was observed for a few days that signing into the B2C app after the account has been enabled is experienced delays, but it was random and no longer occurring.

Please is there any idea what might have caused this?

Comment: How much delay till it worked? Some delay is expected due to replication.

Comment: About 5 minutes delay. The delays started occurring recently (April 8th) which is why it has caused some concern